# Avoid dependentAssembly within app.config (.net framework)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, app-config, assemblies

I'm looking for a way to avoid the need to add dependentAssembly within the app.config file.
The actual related project is a library that should be added to a global process. It's not possible to modify the app.config of the global process (.net Framework).

**Example of the issue:**

1.When adding nuget package Application Insights to my console app => It would not add a 'dependentAssembly' section within my app.config. The Application insights lib works fine when doing a test as well.

2.When adding the nuget package Serilog & Serilog Application Insights, it adds a new 'dependentAssembly' section within the app.config file. This one works fine as well.

**However**, when removing the 'dependentAssembly' section that is related to application insights, the following error occurs :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights,
> Version=2.12.0.21496, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

==> This isn't the only serilog plugin that has this kind of issue.
The configuration builder includes also 'dependentAssembly' sections within the app.config.

**The appconfig example can be found here :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.16.0.18277" newVersion="2.16.0.18277" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The error msg informs that it's looking for Version=2.12.0.21496 while i'm using version 2.16 of application insights. This can be fixed by installing v2.12.., but i don't want to rely on this as it can be different for every server.

Is there another way to define the version nr?

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,
Kurt